# Scrollableview causing app crash appcelerator ios

Tags: ios, iphone, memory, appcelerator-titanium, scrollable

I am devloping an app using appceleartor titanium,I am adding four pages to the scrollableview,when i scroll multiple times app will crash in the iphone 5,but it will working fine in simulators and iphone 6s plus device.

It will showing the following error.

```
 [INFO] :   Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error:   0x38aee654> {     count = 1, contents =
[INFO] :    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x38aee854> { length =       22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
[INFO] :   }>
[INFO] :   Received memory warning.
[INFO] :   LaunchServices: disconnect event received for service com.apple.lsd.mapdb
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[INFO] :   Received memory warning. - the reason of crash.

The main idea that Memory is running out, because of that it is working fine on the newest devices and simulators, but older ones will report you crash.

Please, check what burdens your app. Are there images on your Scrollable view?